# AddTemporarySigningCredential vs AddSigningCredential in IdentityServer4

Tags: identityserver4

According to the docs, IdentityServer uses an asymmetric key pair to sign and validate JWTs.
One could either use `AddTemporarySigningCredential()` in the configuration which creates a fresh RSA every startup or use `AddSigningCredential(..)` with an RSA key or a certificate.

The document mentions the Temporary version is useful for Development situations but it does not tell what is the disadvantage of this when used in a production environment.

I have a aspnetcore web api in which the clients are authenticated using the IdentityServer4. The system works fine at the moment with the temporarysigningcredential but I wonder whether there is any benefit in using the other variant.

Thanks,

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The disadvantage is, that every time you restart IdentityServer, the key material will change - or IOW - all tokens that have been signed with the previous key material will fail to validate.

"Temporary" is really only for situations where you don't have other key material available.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what would happen to a client who tries to authenticate using the old key material in this example? Will it simply request a new token?

Answer (score 26):

Instead of AddTemporarySigningCredential consider to use **AddDeveloperSigningCredential**

From http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/startup.html#refstartupkeymaterial:

**AddDeveloperSigningCredential**

> Same purpose as the temporary signing credential. But this version
>   persists the key to the file system so it stays stable between server
>   restarts. This addresses issues when the client/api metadata caches
>   get out of sync during development.

WARNING: **AddDeveloperSigningCredential** can be used only when IdentityServer host is running on a **SINGLE** machine, for production farm you need to use **AddSigningCredential**.

Comment: AddTemporary seems to be missing in the latest Preview supporting .net core??

Comment: @RasmusChristensen, correct, see https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/1139

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim how does one set up the `.AddSigningCredential()`?

Comment: @J86, It is a separate question, that has a few answers on SO, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48086994/identityserver4-addsignercredentials-rsa-example and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49042474/addsigningcredential-for-identityserver4